# AWS Certificate request not issued. Error : The status of this certificate request is "Pending validation"

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

[Record suceessfully created in DNS server but certificate request is Pending.Error is show in the following link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKh5T.png)

Comment: Is `test.org` actually your domain?

Comment: yes,it is my host zone

Comment: Hosted zone and actual domain are two different things.

Comment: Yes,you are right and issue is solved.Problem is that my domain is not active .AWS crtificate is issued after activated domain.

Thank you Marchin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by using wrong domain in ACM. The solution was to use correct domain for which OP is owner of.

Comment: @RonakBhatti No problem. Glad it worked out.